# Change Swift constraint on if statement

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

Here is my tableview row/cell:

[image]

there are constraints set in place - the imageview is below the label and the button is below the imageview.

here is my code:

```
if(row == 1) {
    imageview.hidden = false
} else {
    imageview.hidden = true
}
```

how can i change the button constraint from below imageview to below label?

Comment: Could you please frame your question in a better way? I can't understand what you wish to achieve from the question in the comment. Also, dont ask question in comment and code part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding and removing constraints is really bad example for that. I'll make your UI more complex.

Best way of solving these auto-layout problems is adding two constraints. One from `imageView` to `button` and second from `imageView` to `label`.

Now after setting these constraints, you need to set their `priority` levels. So, let's say `button` will be below the `imageView` first. In this case, you need to set imageView to button constraint's priority to something like 750 or `UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh` and label to button constraint's priority to 250 or `UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow`.

Let's start creating a custom UITableViewCell

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonToLabelConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonToImageViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func shouldHideImageView(hidden: Bool) {
        if(hidden == false) {
          buttonToLabelConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
          buttonToImageViewConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
          imageView.hidden = true
        } else {
          buttonToLabelConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh
          buttonToImageViewConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
          imageView.hidden = false
        }
        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

After that, in your class where tableView is placed implement a logic like that:

```
if(row == 1) {
  cell.shouldHideImageView(true)
} else {
  cell.shouldHideImageView(false)
}
```

You should be all set.

Comment: how do i create two constraints and call them?

Comment: you can create them in Interface Builder or programmatically. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: I can't teach you. But you can google it. If you don't know how to create auto layout constraint then follow some tutorials. I can provide you two links. Working Auto layouts in Interface builder from here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-auto-layout-basics--cms-25520 and programmatically form here https://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/ . If you follow these tutorials, you can learn them.

Comment: yes i know how to make constraints with interface builder but how do i make 2 sets of constraints and then call each one in the different if else statement?

Comment: Create these constraints in Interface builder. Set their default priorities  in Interface Builder as I described. Then create IBOutlet properties for those constraints. Then, you can access them in if else statement.

Comment: okay i did exaclty what you said and it does not change anything.

Comment: did you call `layoutIfNeeded` method?

Comment: yes i did, `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` but it still doesnt work

Comment: No, there is something wrong here. If this is your cell, you should create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass to do these things. You can't do things like that in a place where your tableView stays.

Comment: My suggestion is, create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. Add this constraint changes to a method in subclass. And call this method when you want to hide/show `imageView`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a StackView, when you tell something to be hidden, the imageView the stack view will adjust the StackView as if the imageView was never a part of the view and it is an easy work around to not have to worry about constraints.

Comment: How do you do that and also what are the down falls?

Comment: First Add a vertical stack view form the object library and constrain it to your cell. Then throw in the two labels and image in the order you desire, and you can set sizes in the distribution section in the attributes inspector. Once you get it how you want, you just tell the image view to be hidden and the stack view will collapse and you will have two label one right above the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `IBOutlet` on constraint and then just simply change the value like this:

```
buttonConstraint.constant = newValue
```

But i suggest you create for this a `tableView`. In this case you code and logic, i think, will be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

you could to this instead of hiding.

1. Make an outlet from the heights constraint of the imageview, call it constraint for now.
2. Set constraint.constant = 0 // effectively same as hiding.
3. Set constraint.constant = NON_ZERO_VALUE  // effectively same as show.

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of options. The first is a little easier to implement but a little less flexible if you decide to change your layout later.

1. Make the button's constraint to be below the label. Keep a reference to this constraint (you can connect it to your code via storyboard just like you do with the button itself, if you're using storyboard). When the imageView is visible, set `myConstraint.constant += myImageView.frame.height`. When the imageView is hidden, set `myConstraint.constant -= myImageView.frame.height`. Afterwards, call `view.setNeedsLayout` to update your constraints.
2. Make two constraints: one for below the image, and one for below the label ("constraintToImage" and "constraintToLabel"). Hook them both up to your controller like in option 1, and call `view.addConstraint(constraintToImage)` and `view.removeConstraint(constraintToLabel)` when the image becomes visible (and the opposite for when it's hidden). Again, call `view.setNeedsLayout` after.